# How to test higher order functions in Clojure?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

How do I test a higher-order function in Clojure ?

I can always test a function that accepts a value and then check returned value against the expected one.

How do I do that with a higher order function ?

Or we generally avoid doing so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question.  To be more precise about the issue:

[Higher-order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/higher-order-functions/info) "take or produce other functions as arguments or results".  So there's two cases:

1. functions that take functions.  Examples: `map`, `reduce`, `filter`.  These aren't too hard to test; just supply all the parameters like you would to a normal function.
2. functions that return functions.  Examples: `(fn [x] (fn [y] (+ x y)))`, `(partial filter #(> % 1))`.
   These are difficult to test because we can't directly compare the equality of functions (search for intensional and extensional equality for a thorough discussion).

   It should be obvious that simply not testing is not a very good strategy.  So why not take the Haskell view that partially applied functions are essentially the same as functions that return functions -- in other words, pass enough parameters to the returned function to get a result that you can test for equality.

   Just be careful to watch out for coupling in your tests -- make sure that your test cases are actually testing the specification of the higher-order function, not just the function that it returns.

Comment: on that note, are macros tested as well specially the doXYZ ones?

Answer (score 2):

Higher order functions still return results so you can still check it.

For example, if you wanted to test `map`, think about what it's supposed to do: It is supposed to get a function and a collection as arguments, apply said function to every item in the collection, returning a new collection of the results.

So a simple way of testing that would be:

```
(is (= [1 2 3 4] (map inc [0 1 2 3]))
```

The same principle applies if you're testing a higher-order function that is the result of another function: you simply test it returns what's supposed to, after calling the function that returns it:

```
(defn adder [n]
  (fn [x]
    (+ x n)))

(is (= ((adder 10) 5) 15))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Thanks, I think I wasn't treating function as values and thinking something else.
As long as there is no mutation, if a higher order function returns a consistent value for a lamda and list, it should be consistent with any lambda function being passed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: but what about functiosn that return closures ?

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't see why it would behave any differently.

Comment: so if a higher order function returns a function that returns 4-5 different functions based on 4-5 different arguments.

say something like (def algebraic-eq (gen-algebraic-func {:x [1,2,3] :y [2,3,4]}))

gen-func returns a func that is an algebraic function which accepts a dictionary of variables as key and vector of coefficients at power  positions in vectors for these variables and returns a function that then takes values of :x,:y etc and returns the result.

Now how do I test such function ?

Matt Fenwick touches that concern.

Comment: This is just an extension of the same principle. It doesn't really matter how many functions you function-generating function returns, as long as you know what they're supposed to do once applied, they are just as well tested using the approach above. And for pure functions like the one you mention, something like [test.generative](https://github.com/clojure/test.generative) can also help as you only need to provide the function spec and the framework makes sure it holds true for several/hundreds of values.